# Reskit parse multiple type of data for the same field

Tags: ios, parsing, restkit

I just want to ask if there is a way to parse the following field "mods" in Reskit:

```
post_count: false,
sitename: "Mercury",
mods: false,
admin_email: "maystro@test.com",
```

here mods has a boolean value and in the next example it has an object as a value:

```
post_count: false,
sitename: "Mercury",
mods: {
0: false,
author_blocks: {
enabled: {
placebo: "placebo"
},
disabled: {
2: "jbckmn",
placebo: "placebo"
}
},
backups: null,
smof_init: "Wed, 14 May 2014 18:53:58 +0000",
custom_logo: "",
custom_logo_height: "1",
custom_login_logo: "",
custom_login_logo_height: "1",
custom_favicon: ""
}
```

In the same JSON response we're receiving this type of data, sometimes mods has a boolean value and sometimes it has an object. Does anyone knows if there is a way to do a dynamic mapping using Restkit to handle such cases?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed yes. You want to use an `RKDynamicMapping`, and return the actual mapping you want to use from that; something like:

```
RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];

[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {
    if ([representation valueForKey:@"MyKey"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        return aMappingWhenTheFieldIsANumber;
    }
    else
    {
        return aMappingWhenTheFieldIsNotANumber;
    }
}];
```

In this manner, you get to pick the mapping to use *when* you have the data in hand. Just check the data for the field type, and return a normal `RKObjectMapping` appropriate for the field types.